# How to create AWS A record with terraform autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-route53, autoscaling

If you have the following launch configuration

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "provisioning" {
    name                 = "app_balancer"
    image_id             = "${var.ami_id}"
    instance_type        = "${var.instance_type}"
    security_groups      = ["${aws_security_group.def.id}"]
    user_data            = "${file("${var.bootstrap_path}")}"
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    iam_instance_profile        = "${var.iam_instance_profile_id}"
    key_name             = "my_key"

    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sleep 15"
    }
  }
```

This works and starts the instance according to  aws_autoscaling_group and aws_autoscaling_policy. But I couldn't be able to find a way to take the new generated IPs and add this information to route53.

Comment: That's not possible. You would have to do this through _user data_ when the instance boots (by calling the R53 API). If you're using TCP/HTTP services, a load balancer helps.

Comment: Or.. the standard answer.. a Lambda that is executed when a scaling event occurs.

Comment: You should probably show the rest of your Terraform code that creates the ASG and explain what you're doing with the ASG (should the instances be behind a load balancer or not? How do you intend to connect to them and why do you need A records?)

Comment: Or.. the other standard answer.. a Load Balancer between your ASG and R53